# Changing listview row color according to conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i am developing a website on writing reports ...users can comment on a report (huh!! as if a new thingy ;))..back to question..what am doing is showing the comments using a `listview`.

**Question:** i want that when someone comments on his own post `the row should be of different color`, so that its clearly visible that the post owner has commented...I have seen this in `Scott Guthrie's` blog..any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: If you've seen it, then it can be done, can't it now..

Comment: any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: set the author id (if I got it right, it will be the currently logged in user) into a session variable... then in listview's ItemDataBound event, change the color if ids match... Alternatively, use javascript or jQuery to color the row with the matching id... no code, not much info = this much answer.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with data keys and the `ItemDataBound` event.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="UserID" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" ... />
```

In addition to the above, you'll also need to wrap each item in a server control so you can adjust the background color:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <!-- the item content here -->
    </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here's some example code-behind:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = e.Item as ListViewDataItem;
    if (dataItem != null)
    {                        
        var innerPanel = dataItem.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
        if (innerPanel!= null)
        {
            var userID = (int)ListView1.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex]["UserID"];
            if (userID == base.User.UserID)
                innerPanel.BackColor = Color.PeachPuff;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: your code works...it changes the color but it changes the color of the whole listview...i mean all the rows.

Comment: @user1150440: Updated my answer to provide further clarification about the wrapper in the `ItemTemplate`. See the second code block for details.

Comment: i want to change the row color of a particular row where commenter = article writer.

Comment: You need to wrap the `ItemTemplate` content in a Panel. See the second code block in my answer for details.

Comment: Thanks a zillion :) Your code works like a charm :) How do you know everything?

Comment: You're very welcome, and I appreciate the compliment. Have I answered some of your questions in the past?

Comment: Ya a lot :) actually my last account got banned due to down votes :( can i use `TryCast(dataItem.FindControl("Label1"), Label)` to get a label from `listview`?

Answer (score 0):

onitemdatabound do a check to see if the commentator id matches the writers id

if it does do something like

```
if(databinder.eval(e.item.dataitem, "commentatorid") == _writerId)
{
    e.item.attributes.add("style", "background-color: red");
}
```

I think it's something like that can't check atm