# Color of output doesn't change

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this C# event handler that suppose to change the color of the text based on the values of the List View

Here is the code:

```
protected void YourListView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Label theTWALabel;
int theTWAValue;
foreach (ListViewItem item in YourListView.Items)
{
    theTWALabel = (Label)item.FindControl("TWALabel");
    theTWAValue = Convert.ToInt32(theTWALabel.Text);
    if (theTWAValue >= 0)
    {
        if (theTWAValue < 90)
            theTWALabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("YellowThis");
        else
            theTWALabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
}
```

and here is the list view line:

```
<asp:ListView id="YourListView"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" OnLoad="YourListView_Load" EnableViewState="False">
```

and here is my list view code:

```
<asp:ListView id="YourListView"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" OnLoad="YourListView_Load" EnableViewState="False">       
    <ItemTemplate>
        Plant Name:
        <asp:Label id="PlantLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plant") %>' />
        <br />
        Department #:
        <asp:Label id="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
        <br />
        Department Name:
        <asp:Label id="GroupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />
        <br />
        Job Code:
        <asp:Label id="Job_CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Code") %>' />
        <br />
        TWA:
        <asp:Label id="TWALabel"   runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TWA") %>' />
        <br />
        Job Classification:
        <asp:Label id="Job_ClassificationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Classification") %>' />
        <br />
        Job Function:
        <asp:Label id="Job_FunctionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Function") %>' />
        <br />
        Job Description:
        <asp:Label id="Job_DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Description") %>' />
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server"  style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; border:3em; border-color:black;">
    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The Problem is that while it will output my listview values correctly, none of the colors change, and I don't why. Any help would be excellent

Edit: Could it be because of my layout template as that controls all the styling?

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to ensure this code actually runs?

Comment: `.FromHtml("YellowThis")` is not a valid Yellow color, try `System.Drawing.Color.Yellow` instead or `.FromHtml("Yellow")` or `.FromHtml("#EEEE00")`

Comment: YellowThis is a style class i made, would it still not be valid?

Comment: And I just changed it to System.Drawing.Color.Yellow and it still didn't work unfortunately

Comment: can you just add a class to each item and let css do the work?

Comment: no because the values are coming from a database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892461/changing-listview-row-color-according-to-conditions

this is what you need to see once

Comment: Well that example is if some one is adding data to the page. I just want from the data i already have change the color of the TWA row, based on its value

Comment: I copied/pasted your `ListView` (adapting the bindings of course) and it works for me. Try commenting/removing all your `CSS` files from your project, just to make sure there's not another style interfering with it.

Comment: I have removed all the css and still nothing, could a js script possibly affect it?

Comment: I removed all of my js scripts and still nothing....

Comment: I pretty sure its my the layout template that is causing the issue, as that has all the styling aspects, but I don't know how i go used that to change the TWA label

Comment: Are the TWA values from your data actually >= 0? I just copied and pasted your code and the code works just fine.

Comment: Whats weird is when I start a new aspx page and try to do the same thing just with no css or any other added things it still doesn't work for me. Is it because I am using microsoft expression?

Comment: @EmmanuelRC Actually is is because before the c# code I have say <script runat="server">?

Comment: Was that a question? if so, to what part/line are you exactly referring to with that?